# Запись текста со страницы в Edit или Label

Tags: delphi

При обращении к странице через браузер `http://192.168.0.1/conninfo.php` (это роутер) он выдает

```
var result = new Array("OK", "connected", "192.112.240.26", "255.255.255.255", "172.16.1.2", "194.28.28.3 8.8.8.8", "");
```

Подскажите, как сделать, чтоб если написано "connected", он, к примеру, выполнил

```
Label1.Caption:= 'трололо';
```

а остальные, там где IP адреса, записал в различные  Label, вобще не важно, какое действие будет происходить, мне важно понять, как изъять инфу со страницы и выполнить условие, в этом деле я понимаю очень мало, поэтому прошу объяснить поподробнее, а лучше готовый скрипт или пример, я разгрызу. Вот еще нашел javascript на странице, мб поможет как-то, я в нем не шарю

```
switch (result[0]) {
case "OK":
    if (result[1] == "connected") {
        result[4] = result[2];

        get_obj("connstate").value = "Подключен";
        get_obj("wanipaddr").innerHTML = "&nbsp;" + result[2];
        get_obj("wansubnet").innerHTML = "&nbsp;" + result[3];
        get_obj("wangateway").innerHTML = "&nbsp;" + result[4];
        get_obj("wandns").innerHTML = "&nbsp;" + result[5];

        get_obj("bt_connect").disabled = false;
    } else {
        get_obj("connstate").value = "Отключен";
        get_obj("wanipaddr").innerHTML = "&nbsp;0.0.0.0";
        get_obj("wansubnet").innerHTML = "&nbsp;0.0.0.0";
        get_obj("wangateway").innerHTML = "&nbsp;0.0.0.0";
        get_obj("wandns").innerHTML = "&nbsp;194.28.28.3&nbsp;8.8.8.8";

        get_obj("bt_connect").disabled = false;
    }
    setTimeout("update_state()", period);
    break;

case "WAIT":
    setTimeout("update_state()", period);
    break;
}
delete result;
```

Comment: Это уже работа за автора

Comment: @hamik Уточните ваш вопрос, он непонятен.

Comment: php страница при обращении к ней  показывает 
var result = new Array("OK", "connected", "192.112.240.26", "255.255.255.255", "172.16.1.2", "194.28.28.3 8.8.8.8", "");
судя по написанному не сложно догадаться что это состояние подключения, как сделать чтоб когда статус "connected" у меня к примеру закрывалось окно, все IP адреса и днс записывались в отдельные Label

Comment: дело немного продвинулось вперед, теперь нужно IP и DNS записать в отдельные поля, Memo, RichEdit или Edit без разницы во что

Answer (score 1):

при помощи функций pos(), copy(), delete()
отпарсить(вырезать) из выдаваемого роутером html кода данные

Например, что бы получить connected из данного вами кода нужно выполнить

```
if(pos("connected",{строка string с кодом выдаваемой страницы})>0 then
{мы нашли коннектед}
```

Comment: очень хрупко, сломается когда мыльница отдаст "disconnected"